# Char array issue in powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am using powershell to get the values from one of the controls of chrome. I am getting the values as string, so i used .tochararray(), so that i can parse the values using foreach loop. But the loop is not parsing each values.

below are the details:
from control i am getting value as 12345. It has got string type.
I used .tochararraay() to convert to array, now i am getting output as :

```
1




2




3




4




5
```

while parsing using foreach loop, i am not able to chck for nulls or blanks. can you please suggest how we can do that.
I have used

```
if ($i-ne " " -or $i-ne $null -or $i-ne ' ')
```

Comment: Was there many blank lines when you used `.ToCharArray()` ?

Comment: yes correct. When used .tochararray(), i am getting many blank lines

Comment: I tried `"12345".ToCharArray()` and got a correct output

Comment: Can you show us the code for the fist part: "get the values from one of the controls of chrome" ?

Comment: $pagecount = $ChromeDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#pageControlsAttachments").Text.ToCharArray()

Comment: Sounds like you want `$pageCounts = -split $ChromeDriver.FindElementByCssSelector("#pageControlsAttachments").Text`

Comment: i tried capturing the output in text file,  and i am getting the defaulted o/p. The o/p is enabled with spaces

Comment: Thanks All. I rectified the issue I added  ? {$_.trim() -ne "" }  to fix the case.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, I encourage you to post it as an answer, though it's not clear to me how the question relates to the solution. The solution implies that you wanted to test for whether the string is either empty or contains whitespace characters only, and that doesn't require inspecting its _individual characters_.